# Make XMLHTTPrequest complete getting objects from json file if there is an error

Tags: javascript

I use JavaScript to get json file from url dynamically. Everything works well till there is an object not existing in the file and the code below this object not executed and it complete executing codes out of the xml request. Now I want to make it complete even if the object not existing and complete executing the other objects which already exist but below the non existent object.

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Getting objects after parsing here
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "url", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: I used try catch but it doesn't solve it

Comment: What do you exactly want?

Comment: To complete executing code after error and not get out of the request. It's aborted if I tried to alert an object not existing in the json file

Comment: Do you have any important code below in this file? Do you want to continue execution irrespective of `error`? Did you mean this?